# Selecting ambiguous constructor manually

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

When a call to a function (member class function or free function) is ambiguous, we can select it easily using `static_cast<>` to the function type we calling:

```
struct S {
    void f(uint32_t, uint8_t) {
        std::cout << "1\n";
    }

    void f(uint32_t, uint32_t) {
        std::cout << "2\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    auto f1 = static_cast<void(S::*)(uint32_t, uint8_t)>(&S::f);
    (s.*f1)(1,1);
    auto f2 = static_cast<void(S::*)(uint32_t, uint32_t)>(&S::f);
    (s.*f2)(1,1);
}
```

But I wonder if it is possible to do something similar for constructors. For example, in the following structure:

```
struct S {
    S(uint32_t, uint8_t) {
        std::cout << "1\n";
    }

    S(uint32_t, uint32_t) {
        std::cout << "2\n";
    }
};
```

Is it possible to manually solve ambiguous constructor call for creating `S s(1,1);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
S s1(static_cast<uint32_t>(1), static_cast<uint32_t>(2));
S s2(static_cast<uint32_t>(1), static_cast<uint8_t>(2));
```

This disambiguates the constructor-calls by specifying the types explicitly in the arguments.

Comment: oops.....<.< didn't see this coming....<.< sometimes I overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just cast to the correct type? `1` is an `int` literal so it makes some "confusion" when passing to unsigned parameters

```
int main() {
    S s;
    s.f(1, (uint8_t)1);
    s.f(1, (uint32_t)1);
    s.f(1, 1U);
}
```

[Demo on Godlbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMz%2BpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgAJykAA6oCoRODB7evgFBaRmOAmER0SxxCcl2mA5ZQgRMxAQ5Pn6Btpj2xQwNTQSlUbHxSbaNza15HQrjA%2BFDFSOJAJS2qF7EyOwc5v7hyN5YANQm/m7IM/iCp9gmGgCCu/uHmCdnTjPEmKw3d48Pny8DiOQhOAHYrA8jtCjgA3VB4dBHKgQLzhAj%2BMwAfQIpCOaMEAA4cctwZD7jDKUdLiAUOsCG83Kc3CczGYuCYAKxuBjmMyncmUkxggAifz%2BlPhiORqPRmJxeIJGOxBFJwsFVOhNLpXgZzOZrLZXJ5fIFEphwrFD0tZutD3RRxYTHCEDVEPN0NBCltFJhCgAdCiuHjZUSSVxlj7KQGgyGlfLVRGo37AxBg0cuHJI/5yTaHhxVrROJzeH4OFpSKhOEzLNZqetNq9djxSARNAXVgBrECSLj%2Bzm9yRggBsXE5iX8YLMiWH%2Bk4klL7crnF4ChAGlb7dWcFgMEQdJYKTo8XIlDQh%2BPCWAXC4Zj4dAI8TXEBiS5i4SaAE9OC3z2xBAA8gwtDfuWvBYE6RjiGBpD4F8dSwpga4wZgqi1Lq2wVuiXRLrQeAxMQX4eFgS4EMQeAsD%2BBZ8AYwAKAAangmAAO4ASkjBUTIggiGI7BSFx8hKGoS66EEBhGCg1jWPo%2BFrpAqyoCkPTIQAtCplynCKpi1pYZgaEcKkAf4BkAOpiLQpmoWRTAGex6CGI4yCrl0tQ9C4DDuJ4bR6KE8zlJUeiFJkAiTH4wZBT0gz%2BSMwY1HUAh9BMXl5LFLnxb0sxRcMCSxbMoV6DM/RZYsOWrAoDZbHoZGYNsPCFsWi4wVWHCqISw4qcOkhHMAyDIBmfZmEcEA1lYlh4rghAkKy/jph4F70MQ03%2BMsvBtmB25IOeR4LaeEBbZeKDide/gaBuNC0I%2BxDPq%2BMHvswxCgb%2BqAsP%2BBBASBS4QYYwDQRWcGuXgiHIRWqHoY%2BS7YUWMF4QRREYJhq3kZR3DUVQtEMUxrHsWWLb8NxojiPxeOCSo6gwbod5HZJOk2DDcmupWSlZKp6kEOgmnaaNFh6QZRmmeZlmqNZtmYPZgh4E5nTdFk7mebk7ScsEHnFQF0gRVk%2BX%2BIr6slH52U9lLAMJXlyUK4b6WJXMZT69IhVJfLASK3bVsLKrZUVXxrZfLV1FQyWpBlhWzWte1nVHAc30Zv4/oaDHQ0jdJRwTUQi3Nnic3bfE01mCtm7rasCDfFgCQM92XCnXOHALqQlGcpy/pcBOYKJISkiSDOt69gHS7Nau6551o257hASD0ikuq7ftC0BME%2BAp3oxM8YTwbE4opNLsxhEpFR9UcP7ge8M1AG6uPDKoFQRwhx1XU9X1N7%2BoNw3PZnqdmIEudrYPpAjyAY8TxQe1n4HTvKLSaOUBJLz4ivWQa9hIwU3kwbeKNd77x7pwY%2BBBT5HHPpfNq19w5HSjjHOOT95pZ12DnVaW4C5FxGKXCQp0Y6nWYSw5hwYobV0om3f0hINDDj0mOTkGh/CEjBOObuTUVy2H7p/DspBuyckJP6SQijORv1bnwswYINDSChv4RqQcpGyOWLvMwBjD5GOoaQRCV0ZaSCAA%3D)

Comment: Don't use "C" style casts